# Should we extend topicality to include questions teachers have?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, site-faq

We will hopefully have a user base consisting of people who want to learn English and people who want to teach English.

Can we, therefore, extend on topic questions to include questions about how to teach English?

Since we will (hopefully) have teachers as well as non-native speakers who have been taught, it seems we would have a good base of people to answer such questions.